# How do I format tables with empty columns in some rows?

Tags: vim, vim-tabular

Example:

```
Names John Doe
Names Cher
Names Jesus H Christ
```

Turns into:

```
Names John    Doe
Names         Cher
Names Jesus H Christ
```

Basically, different rows have different number of items. But I want to align the last item in a row together and pad empty columns for all of the previous items.

I'm trying to use vim-tabular. Is there a way to do this using that?

Comment: I'm not suggesting to cross-post but it might a good idea to look at https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ahh thank you. I posted here because another vim question was asked.

Comment: it's fine to post questions about vim here too.